# How can I use jQuery variables for this image gallery overlay?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, gallery

so I'm making a portfolio gallery as a part of a website I'm building for a little practice. 
On hover I'm trying to get an overlay, as this didn't work on phones I thought it would be a good idea to make a jquery fallback. This is my code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
  $('.overlay-1').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', '1')
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).css('opacity', '0')
    });
  });
  $('.overlay-2').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', '1')
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).css('opacity', '0')
    });
  });
  $('.overlay-3').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('opacity', '1')
    $(this).mouseleave(function() {
      $(this).css('opacity', '0')
    });
  });
  });
```

It goes on in this fashion, to enable users to see the overlay when a certain image is clicked. Surely there is a better way of writing all this? Maybe using variables, I'm not sure

Thanks guys!

Comment: You are not sure, why you don't try it. It's just code. break down that shit and make it better.. What better is, you will lern when time passes and you get more experience ;) welcome to stackoverflow, happy coding

Comment: You are on the right track and its good that you realized there might be a better way of doing it. A good rule of thumb is when your see duplication of your code such as the internals of each of your mouse enter and mouse leave you break that out into a single function to keep your code "dryer". I would take a look into using the jquery ".on" method and you can be less specific with your selectors.

Answer (score 0):

I would give each overlay the same class and then toggle a class that lowers/raises the `opacity` on `click` (not `mouseenter`/`mouseleave` since its for mobile fallback). For example:

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/okhn7qup/1/)

New class to add/remove on click:

```
.opacity-lower {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JQuery - Toggle Class

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.overlays').click(function () {
           $(this).toggleClass('opacity-lower');
       });
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function show() {$(this).css('opacity', 1);}
function hide() {$(this).css('opacity', 0);}

[1,2,3].forEach(function(num) {
    $('overlay-'+num).mouseenter(show).mouseleave(hide);
});
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to provide explanation as to how this solves the problem?